# Rounding bug in Python's Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, debugging, rounding

I'm not sure if it is a bug or not. In below code, I got `[0.0, 0.0, 0.1]` and `[0.0, 0.1, 0.1]` as output, which are different. But I expected that both of the 2 `print()` output `[0.0, 0.1, 0.1]`

```
import numpy as np
print([round(x,1) for x in np.array([0.049, 0.05, 0.0501])])
print([round(x,1) for x in [0.049, 0.05, 0.0501]])
```

Comment: I'd read the notes in: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html, specifically the area talking about the difference between numpy's rounding and Python's built-in rounding.

Comment: @alkasm Both numpy and Python3 are rounding a half to the nearest even number. The numpy behaviour is therefore understandable, but the Python behaviour is not, at least to me. The question to ask is why `round(0.05, 1) != 0`?

Comment: @zvone Because of floating point approximations. 0.05 is not exactly 0.05.

Comment: @khelwood Yeah, figured that out, but why does it work with numpy? Does it have some smart way to detect that 0.05 is actually 0.05 and not 0.0500000000something?

Comment: The duplicate is not appropriate here. That question is about round-half-to-even. round-half-to-even isn't really relevant here, because `0.05` is not an exact tie.

Comment: @zvone: NumPy is doing the naive thing of multiplying by `10`, rounding to the nearest integer, and dividing by `10` again. The multiplication by `10` incurs a rounding error which has the lucky (or unlucky, depending on your viewpoint) side-effect of turning something that wasn't an exact tie into something that _is_ an exact tie. Python is doing a correct rounding based on the exact value of the input (so here, `0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125`).

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks, that is the info I was looking for. Do you know, is that documented somewhere? I could not find it.

Comment: @zvone Sorry, I don't know if it's documented. I got my information by looking at the source.